# Show input textbox upon response from rest api in sign up policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have 5 fields visible to the user in my signup form. Once the user fills all the fields and click on signup, we will be calling a rest api and the response will return a true/false value.

If the response variable returns true, we need to show a 6th field and make it mandatory for the user to be able to successfully finish the signup.

Is it possible to achieve this workflow in Azure AD B2C Signup Policy?

Thanks

Comment: Can someone please help me out with this